# Angular 5 Jasmine issue in VS code

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

I am totally new to Angular 5 Unit testing. I have installed all @types/jasmine but still i am getting errors in spec.ts file like describle is not a name and jasmine.createSpyObj does not exists on the typeof Jasmine. Please be informed i have imported jasmine in my spec file. import {} from 'jasmine'(no use though)

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
        "es2017",
        "dom"
    ]
}
```

please be informed i tried all possibilities but still not clear my i am getting issue in `Spec.ts` file. Even the intellisense in VS code is not working, to be precise i am seeing all erroneous semnatics error.

Answer (score 1):

Just a tip, after having this same issue:

I had this problem when opening a folder with multiple projects. When I opened a single project with the tsconfig.json in the root folder. The problem went away.

Perhaps this is also your answer.

Comment: Hi Paul, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7cO49cmcAYs&feature=youtu.be&t=58. Too bad nope, that isn't me.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
require('karma-jasmine'),
require('karma-spec-reporter'),
require('karma-verbose-reporter'),
require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma'),
```

Try adding these plugins in the karma.conf.js. Hope this helps